# Python, как открыть картинку?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть исходный код, где картинка читается с `url`.

Пример:

```
import matplotlib.image as image
from urllib.request import urlopen

        with urlopen(url) as file:
            image = image.imread(file, 0)
...
```

Дальше идет исполнение кода. И все работает.

Теперь, хочу открыть картинку из файла:

```
with open(accepted_path, "rb") as file:
    image = image.imread(file, 0)
```

И тут я получаю различные ошибки. Где я нарушаю логику.

Пути, как до `файла`, так и до `url` корректны.

P.S видел [библиотеку](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/), но хочется сделать без нее.

Comment: `imread` может принимать на вход прямо имя файла, не обязательно для него заранее файл открывать. Какие ошибки вы получаете - укажите их текст в вопросе.

Comment: TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response tuple. The tuple must have the form (body, status, headers), (body, status), or (body, headers).

Comment: Ошибка говорит про view function, но в показанном вами коде нет никакого view function. Вы явно от нас что-то скрываете, например использование Flask

Comment: Да, кстати, а что за второй параметр `0` у вас передаётся в `imread`?

Comment: Формат, по стандарту она принимает png, если ничего не указано.

Comment: Вынужден скрывать, политика компании ((

Comment: Тогда мы никак не сможем вам помочь, нам обязательно нужен [mcve]. Обращайтесь за помощью к вашей компании тогда